AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED] When Trying to Publish Node.js Application with Render after Querying Data from PostgreSQL
I am encountering an error while trying to publish my Node.js application with Render. The application queries data from PostgreSQL, and during the publishing process, I receive the following error:
   Connection error: AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]:
  at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1116:18)
  at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1683:7) {
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
 [errors]: [
  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5432
    at createConnectionError (node:net:1646:14)
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1676:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 5432
},
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at createConnectionError (node:net:1646:14)
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1676:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432
}
]
}

index.js file
 require('dotenv').config();
 const express = require("express")
 const app = express()
 const path = require("path")
 const tasarim = path.join(__dirname,'../tasarim')
 const fs = require('fs');
 const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


     app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log('uygulama başarılı bir şekilde açılıyor ');
     });
     app.use('/tasarim', express.static('tasarim'));

    app.use('/images', express.static('images'));
     app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
    app.use(express.json())
    app.set("view engine","ejs")
    app.set("views",tasarim)

    app.use(express.urlencoded({
        extended:false
     }))



    const { Client } = require('pg');
    const client = new Client({
       host: process.env.DB_HOST,
       port: process.env.DB_PORT,
       database: process.env.DB_NAME,
       user: process.env.DB_USER,
       password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD, 
    });

  client.connect()
     .then(() => console.log('PostgreSQL veritabanına bağlandı'))
     .catch(err => console.error('Bağlantı hatası', err));

   



app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
 try {
    let query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1=1'; 

    
    

    res.render(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'tasarim', 
     'index.ejs'), { 
        users,
       
    });
 } catch (err) {
    console.error('Veri alınamadı:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Veri alınamadı');
  }
 });

.env file
 DB_USER=
 DB_PASSWORD=
 DB_NAME=
 DB_HOST=localhost
 DB_PORT=5432

I would like to understand the cause of this error and how to resolve it. My Node.js application fetches data from PostgreSQL successfully, but encounters this error when trying to publish it using Render. What could be the possible reasons for this error, and what steps can I take to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
